# Run a a script from system python interpreter from an external python interpreter

Tags: python, xbmc

XBMC has it's own python interpreter inside of it.

From this built in interpreter I need to run a script on the local machine python(i.e. the system python).

I call `os.system("python myScript.py")`  but I get back the error in my system error:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

I was hoping for ideas of guidance on how to troubleshoot this issue.
Is it even possible to do?
I'm thinking it has something to do with the pythonpath/pythonhome variable.

Comment: Is there a good reason, why you don't just import the script? That should also work, shouldn't it?

Comment: you should probably indeed start looking at the import paths.

Comment: Yes David!  That would be the best solution BUT the script I'm calling (the Leap motion API) has to call a system level script itself.

Comment: Can you start Python from the commandline?

Comment: Yes! Python works great from command line.
And I can even run my test script from the command line.
I'm finding out my xbmc pythonpath is different from my system python path.
So basically when I make a os.system it's not calling my local machine system python apparently.

Answer (score 0):

If you can locate your XBMC python interpreter's path (I would imagine it has the same `python` and is located inside `xbmc/bin/` or something similar), you could run *that* python version instead of the default one when running `python`.

Your code should like so:

```
os.system(python_fullpath + " " script_fullpath)
```

Where both `python_fullpath` and `script_fullpath`, as the names imply, are full paths to those files.

Like, for example:

```
python_fullpath = "C:\Program Files\XBMC\bin\python.exe"
script_fullpath = "C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\myScript.py"
```